# Filling nodata values in geotiff with data from another raster

Tags: python-2.7, raster, gdal

I have two overlapping raster files of different resolutions (A=25m and B=5m). I would like to fill in the nodata values in B (-999) with the values in A in the fastest most efficient way (if possible using python bindings for automation).

I have tested different methods:

1. Resampling raster A to the resolution of B using gdalwarp, and then using gdal_calc for formula `gdal_calc.py -A MNT_5m.tif -B BATI_5m.tif --outfile=out.tif --calc="maximum(A,B)"` but that didn't do anything and the resampling is a time consuming operation.
2. Using gdal_calc again with calc formula `--calc="A*(B=-999)+B*(B!=-999)"` but that gives me the following error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Can anybody help me get this right please ?

Answer (score 1):

If the nodata values are properly set (in the metadata), using gdal.BuildVRT might be a nice method to do this.

`BuildVRT` allows for resolution difference, so you could perhaps skip the warp step. But the projection must be the same for all files.

The file listed first in the command ends up "on top", so that should be your 5m file, followed by the 25m file.

```
import gdal

dsvrt = gdal.BuildVRT('output.vrt', ['MNT_5m.tif', 'BATI_25m.tif'],
                      resolution='highest', resampleAlg=gdal.GRA_Bilinear)
```

If a VRT file as output is not sufficient you can easily use `Translate` to turn in into a `TIFF` or something else:

```
dstif = gdal.Translate('output.tif', dsvrt)

dsvrt = None
dstif = None
```

If you do need to use `gdal.Warp`, you can add it before `gdal.BuildVRT` and pass the returned `Dataset` into the BuildVRT (as opposed to the filename as a string).

A benefit of this way of working is that you can easily switch between outputting intermediate files or not. By using `/vsimem/tempfile` as the output, and the `VRT` as the output format, you can do all intermediate steps on-the-fly (in-memory). And if you want the outputs, for debugging or other purposes, changing the filename to a location on disk gives you the intermediate results.